# Social Network Application Design

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to determine the best design for an application that will access several different social network APIs.  Here is an interface that I haven't settled on because it just doesn't feel quite right.  I'd like to know what would be a better design approach to this problem...

```
public interface ISocialNetworkAPI<TApiEntity> where TApiEntity : SocialNetworkEntity
{
    List<TApiEntity> GetAllFollowersFor(string networkUserName);
    List<TApiEntity> GetAllFriendsFor(string networkUserName);
    List<long> GetFollowerIdsFor(long networkUserId);
    List<long> GetFollowerIdsFor(string networkUserName);
    List<long> GetFriendIdsFor(string networkUser);
    TApiEntity GetUser(string networkUserName);
}
```

I'm also planning on using a DI container to inject the appropriate social network concrete object based on the context of the call.

Comment: You might look at the adapter design pattern... Each Adapter would adhere to the interface you have above. MySpaceAPIAdapter, FacebookAPIAdapter...

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [OpenSocial](http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/)? It's Google attempts at a standard social network API. Perhaps you should be modelling it off that if not using it outright.

Comment: Yeah, I know this problem has been solved.  This is really a thought experiment to better myself in OO design.

Comment: +1 - Good answer. Phil, you might want to see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575217/whats-a-good-example-for-class-inheritance/575242#575242  The task you've given yourself above is way too difficult to serve as a learning task unless you have a lot of experience already.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the adapter design pattern... Each Adapter would adhere to the interface you have above. MySpaceAPIAdapter, FacebookAPIAdapter...