# Patterns/Practices for designing Web Services

Tags: design-patterns, soa

Are there any good patterns/practices used while designing Services. I came across this post today:

[When to Use the Decorator Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549743/when-to-use-the-decorator-pattern/1549771#1549771)

Though I didn't completely understand but it really gives a new direction to think about designing services.

Note: This question is not any technology specific.

Answer (score 2):

1. Follow a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) model.
2. Rigorously validate incoming data.
3. Avoid SQL injection, and other code exploits.
4. In general, work with large chunks of data; i.e. records instead of fields.
5. Build your services on a transaction (Unit of Work) basis.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my list:

1. Read a book on real-life service design. For a Restful approach i recommend [Restful Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260)
2. **Spec it**: Designing a service in human code is much easier to discuss and change than implementing it and then discover it's wrong.
3. **Write integration (service tests) in a different language**: You can be fooled into thinking that your service is real spiffy by using the same tech on both client and server. Implementing a RESTful service in Java?, then write your service tests in (J)Ruby, creating .NET SOAP service ? then write your service tests in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Check **SOA Patterns** at http://www.soapatterns.org/

I think you can get some insight into the subject and find good ideas browsing there...

Answer (score 0):

I like to divide the services in two kinds:
1.- Business services with the following layers: 
ddbb
dal (group functionality, ddd's repository style)
bll (entities, business actions)
sil (DTOs, conversion from dto to entity and security)

2.- orchestration services (bpel style): it groups business services for achieving something.

I do not like REST so much, I prefer SOAP.