# Decorator design pattern and Java I/O

Tags: java, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decorator Pattern for IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366385/decorator-pattern-for-io)

Can anyone explain the concept and use of decorator pattern in java I/O please?
thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you don't understand, and what you already know about the Decorator pattern?