# Java FileHandling classes hierarchy Logic

Tags: java, bufferedreader, outputstream, file-handling

i just learned  File Handling yesterday . There is  a confusion  about classes  usage  for me . For Example   some of the examples were like this

```
  Paths  myfile= paths.get("c:\\Sample.txt");
  OutputStream  opt= new  BufferedOutputStream(myfile.hew OutputStream(CREATE));
  BufferedWriter br= new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(opt));
  br.write();.....  ;       

and so on
```

This is  one way and  Somewhere i find

```
  BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("c:\\Sample.txt"));
  bf.write("Hello  File Handling ");'
```

i  am not concerned if  in above code it is creating file  and second one is writing   . i want to ask

in First one we  are using parent (OutputStream)class and then   code goes ,
and in second one we  use   BufferedWriter    Directly instead of using  Parent  one , So what's the logic to do so , i  mean  does it make any difference if we use parent classes  while doing something big  or we can go for any logic

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but the Java IO classes use the Decorator pattern to achieve different ways of reading and writing from an Input or Output Stream.  What this allows is flexibility with how data is loaded and written, since each one allows you to decorate the current type.

[Decorator Pattern for IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366385/decorator-pattern-for-io)

[Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)