# Why it is advisable to wrap a BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write() operations may be costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters?

Tags: java, file, filewriter, bufferedwriter

My question is, whether it is direct use, as shown below;

```
class Test{    
public static void main(String args[]){       
  try{ 
    FileWriter fo =new FileWriter("somex.txt"); 
    int arr[] = {9}; 
    for(int i =0; i <arr.length; i++){
      fo .write(arr[i]); // this is very costly.
    }
    fo.write(b); 
    fo.close(); 
    System.out.println("....");
 }catch(Exception e){system.out.println(e);}     
 } 
}
```

OR

coding it more efficient as shown below;

```
class Test{     
 public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  
   BufferedWriter bfw= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out")));  

   int arr[] = {9};
   for(int i =0; i <arr.length; i++){
      bfw .write(arr[i]); 
    }

   bfw.flush();  
   bfw.close();  

   System.out.println(".......");  
 }  
}
```

There is no difference because both will do same write operation. Can someone help me understand the subtleness?

Comment: The buffered writer won't write until it reaches it's buffer size...This allows for less writes and io operations are costly so if i write 1 time compared to you writing 10 times the 1 write will be better...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462705/how-does-bufferedwriter-work-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BufferedWriter` will store the contents in memory until it reaches it's buffer size then it will do one big write vs. writing directly each time for `FileWriter`.  So with the `FileWriter` every iteration of your loop there will be a write.  The `BufferedWriter` may only write once at the end of your loop depending on your buffer size.