# Decorator pattern java.io.reader

Tags: java, decorator, java-io

For a school report I have to explain how the java.io.Reader package implements the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). I have seen multiple explanations for the java.io package ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366385/decorator-pattern-for-io) for example) but not for the java.io.Reader package (if that's even any different). Here is what I have now, I know this design doesn't show it correctly, but I am not sure how the java.io.Reader package actually does implement it.

[image: decorator java.io.Reader]

So in this case the `Reader` would be the `Component`, the `InputStreamReader` the `Concrete Component`, the `BufferedReader` the `Decorator` and the `LineNumberReader` the `Concrete Decorator`. Again, I know this is wrong but I don't know how to correctly display it.

Comment: The case is correct; you could add `<<decorator>>` to BufferedReader. Personally I would not really call this an example of a decorator pattern. What argues pro: BufferedReader wraps an other Reader. And even though it is not an interface, it has LineNumberReader to make a similar diagram. You could argue that delegating to the the same interface as constructor parameter _"decorates"_.

Comment: Adding LineNumberReader is a bit farfetched, just to have a similar diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram is correct. If you have access to Intellij (or other capable tool) you can see the UML class diagram for Java types. The below snippet is one such diagram.

[image]

As you can see, it agrees with yours. One thing I would consider though is `BufferedReader` a *concrete decorator* since it provides additional behavior on `Reader`.

Comment: Thanks! What would you say would be a decorator instead of a concrete decorator in this case? I still dont really get the difference.

Comment: @MeesKluivers, no problem. I would say, according to the definition, a decorator would be a class that wraps the `Reader` but doesn't add any *new* behavior or functionality.