# Classes with dormant parameters, any cleanup suggestions?

Tags: java, .net, oop, design-patterns

Many a times a constructor has some params are `optional` while object creation. They are later on set with setters ( eg: during lazy initialization ).

My question is there can be some cases when a parameter can never be set via a constructor or a setter at all. For sake of this question, I am calling such instance variables - `dormant`. Asume a standard pizze example, where `Pizza(cheese, chicken, toppings).`. A customer may not want topping and may leave it `dormant.`

Is this considered bad practice ? If yes then are there any known patterns to clean such classes with `dormant` instance variables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is what you need:

> The decorator pattern can be used to extend (decorate) the functionality of a certain object statically, or in some cases at run-time, independently of other instances of the same class.

See a .NET example here:

[Please help me understand the "Decorator Pattern" with a real world example.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2707401/558486)

And here you can find a Java example:

[Gang of Four – Decorate with Decorator Design Pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/gang-four-%E2%80%93-decorate-decorator)