# Access inherited member

Tags: c#

I have this `LoanWithClient` Model that inherits from `Loan`:

```
public class LoanWithClient : Loan
{
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

How can I access the **entire** inherited `Loan` object without having to explicitly write its properties?

> LoanWithClient does not contain a definition for Loan

```
return new LoanWithClient
{
     **Loan** = loan, //The Loan is erroring: LoanWithClient does not contain a definition for Loan
     Client = client
};
```

Class Loan:

```
public class Loan
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    //etc..
}
```

Comment: post definition for class `Loan`

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what "inheritance" means. It means that the derived class (`LoanWithClient`) takes on the features (methods, properties, etc.) of its parent (`Loan`). If neither `LoanWithClient` nor `Loan` have a property `Loan`, then you won't be able to use it when constructing an instance. If `Loan` has an `Amount` property, you can use this directly as you do with `Client`.

Comment: Create a constructor and call the base-class constructor from it. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-the-base-constructor-in-c-sharp

Comment: Also, your object model looks a bit suspicious. Is address really a property of a loan?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [the decorator pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707401/understand-the-decorator-pattern-with-a-real-world-example) (see also: [decorator pattern Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern))

Comment: Don't mix up *is-a* and *has-a*. `LoanWithClient` *is* a `Loan`. It doesn't *have* a `Loan`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class `LoanWithClient` inherits from `Loan`. Which means that the child class have all the properties of parent class. But this doesn't mean that the child class contains a parent class as a property. You can write the class like this-

```
public class Loan
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    //etc..
}

public class LoanWithClient
{
    public Loan Loan { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}

return new LoanWithClient
{
     Loan = loan,
     Client = client
};
```

If you want to keep your class architecture, you can return like the below way-

```
return new LoanWithClient
{
     ID = loan.ID,
     Address = loan.Address,
     City = loan.City,
     //etc..
     Client = client
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to

> Access inherited member

**Loan** is not a member, it's the parent.
Access **Loan**'s members like this:

```
return new LoanWithClient
{
     ID = loan.ID,
     Address = loan.Address,
     City = loan.City,
     //etc...
     Client = client
};
```