# What does it mean for a collection to be “backed by” another?

Tags: java, collections

Can someone explain this property with use cases by an example.

Comment: question is too broad

Comment: putting it into some context, making your example more concrete will be better. like `list interface is backed by linked list` ...

Comment: Do you mean [that](https://coderanch.com/t/591336/certification/Backed-Collection-java) ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html  . I just read from the link written as  "which return a new collection backed by a specified collection, and a few other odds and ends"

Comment: How is this too broad?  It's clear what this question means and it has a fairly straightforward answer.  Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class (and some other class of the [Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html)) it means that a Collection is a "wrapper" of another Collection: the inner class stores the data and the outer class adds some behavior that the inner one hasn't.  An example are the methods of `Collections` whose name starts with `synchronized` or `unmodifiable`: the method [`synchronizedList(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) adds synchronization to any given `List`, the method [`unmodifiableList(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) makes any given `List` unmodifiable and so on.

See also the [Decorator Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707401/understand-the-decorator-pattern-with-a-real-world-example).