# Use for the adapter pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I've been learning the adapter and facade design patterns for an upcoming junior development role i'm applying for, as i'm expecting to be asked what i know about the pattern and times i've used it. While the pattern itself seems straight forward - i'm struggling to think of a practical use i could use it for in a personal project.

So can anyone suggest an idea for a use for it within a small personal project?

Also does the pattern appear anywhere within the Java API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Examples of GoF Design Patterns ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)

Comment: @Thilo - I don't see it as a duplicate but the link is valuable, it contains answers for the last part of the question (Java API)

Comment: probably a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478225/when-do-we-need-adapter-pattern

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For uses in `Java API` of design patterns, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns) question.

Quoting `Wikipedia`:

> In computer programming, the adapter
>   pattern (often referred to as the
>   wrapper pattern or simply a wrapper)
>   is a design pattern that translates
>   one interface for a class into a
>   compatible interface.

So you will use it quite rarely. It is just adapting two incompatible interfaces.

And remember when you don't need a design pattern, just don't use it. Only because it is written in the big books, it doesn't mean it serves all your needs and you must follow it blindly.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this counts as an adapter (maybe it does a little more than a pure interface conversion, what with translating bytes to characters), but how about `java.io.InputStreamReader`, which turns an InputStream into a Reader?

And maybe `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` is a facade that hides the detailed interactions between Threads, and Queues, and Runnables from the user?

Comment: Javadoc says, that `InputStreamReader` is a *Bridge* but I do not agree because the bridge pattern would require `InputStreamReader` to be abstract, while it is concrete. So yes, to me it adapts a real InputStream to the Reader interface.

Answer (score 3):

Head First Design patterns starts the chapter about the Adapter pattern with these words:

> In this chapter we're going to attempt such impossible feats as putting a square peg into a round hole.

The purpose is to *make [some objects] interfaces look like something they're not*. I doubt that you use this pattern while you design an application. It's useful if you have an existing application and you need to make it work with 3rd party libraries or tools.

There is one Adapter in the Java API that we all know, although it's quite hidden. You get is with a fectory method from `Arrays`:

```
Arrays.asList(T... a)
```

The method returns an instance of `Arrays.ArrayList` and this object adapts the array to the List interface.

Answer (score 2):

Adapter pattern is required in following scenario:

Say you have defined an interface `I1` with method `M1` and `M2`

`C1` and `C2` implements this interface `I1`, now for `C1` while implementing `M1` and `M2` you have found no help from other existing classes so you need to write all logic by yourself.

Now while implementing class `C2` you have come across class `C3` with methods `M3` and `M4` that can be used to implement `M1` and `M2` for `C2` so to utilize those `M3` and `M4` in class `C2` you extends class `C3` and use `M3` and `M4` of `C3`.

In this example `C2` becomes `Adapter class` and `C3` becomes `adaptee`

```
package com.design.patterns;

public class AdapterExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape line = new LineShape();
        line.draw();

        Shape text = new TextShape();
        text.draw();
    }
}

//==Start from here
interface Shape{
    public void draw();
}

class LineShape implements Shape{
    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("write some logic and draw line");
    }   
}

//Adapter
class TextShape extends TextView implements Shape{
    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("logic is already there in class TextView");
        drawText();
    }   
}

// Adaptee
class TextView{
    public void drawText() {
        System.out.println("Drawing Text Shape");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a real-world example of the adapter pattern, check out my answer to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478225/when-do-we-need-adapter-pattern/3480547#3480547).