# Design Pattern Question to use for Scenario

Tags: design-patterns

I am writing an application that will post a message to an internal wiki page and an internal message service. I anticipate that I will need to post this message to additional interfaces down the road. Because of this, it seemed like a good opportunity to learn to use design-patterns. I'm a bit new to design patterns.

I've been reviewing them [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx). My question is, for my scenario, what do you think is the best option? They seem to overlap in some cases. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is there to rescue you ;)

For an elaborated [example](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-05/04-qa-0525-observer.html?page=2)

You can do something like this

```
public void postMessage(Message message) { // you can 
    // save message

    // now notify :))
    notifyObservers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the various "destination" services each have a different API, an Adapter pattern will likely make your life a little easier.  See my response to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478225/when-do-we-need-adapter-pattern/3480547#3480547) for greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to deal with messages and routing them to services, I would recommend taking a look at the [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/).  They were specifically designed to handle the case where you are taking a message in and needing to transform it and send it elsewhere.