# What to do if classes with same interface having similar but different method signature?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

What to do if classes with same interface having similar but different method signature?

Let's say I have a project to calculate different costs (to get a total cost at last).

In my program, there is several calculator classes, namely `ACostCalculator`, `BCostCalculator` and so on. When a `calculate()` method is invoked to calculate a cost, a cost container is passed to those cost calculators too. In a good scenario, I can make a `CostCalculator` Interface for every cost calculators.

However, the calculation for different cost required different resources. In my current program, it make be like:

```
//getResource() are costly method while several costs need this. So do it outside calculate() method.
ResourceA resourceA = getResourceA(); 
ResourceB resourceB = getResourceB();

CostContainer costContainer = new CostContainer();
CostCalculator aCostCalculator = new ACostCalculator();
...
CostCalculator eCostCalculator = new ECostCalculator();

aCostCalculator.calculate(costContainer);
bCostCalculator.calculate(costContainer)
cCostCalculator.calculate(costContainer, resourceA);
dCostCalculator.calculate(costContainer, resourceA);
eCostCalculator.calculate(costContainer, resourceA, resourceB);
```

If the signature is exactly the same, I may make a loop conveniently to do it at once. However, since they are similar but different, I can't even make a good interface.

I am not sure if there is good ways to do so. What I can think of is generalizing all `calculate()` method to into

```
calculate(CostContainer costContainer, List<Object> resources);
```

Any ideas? Thanks for answering.

Comment: ...or varargs instead of the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the resources stay the same for the lifetime of the calculators: pass the resources to the constructor of the calculators.

```
ResourceA resourceA = getResourceA(); 
ResourceB resourceB = getResourceB();

CostContainer costContainer = new CostContainer();

CostCalculator aCostCalculator = new ACostCalculator();
CostCalculator bCostCalculator = new BCostCalculator();
CostCalculator cCostCalculator = new CCostCalculator(resourceA);
CostCalculator dCostCalculator = new DCostCalculator(resourceA);
CostCalculator eCostCalculator = new ECostCalculator(resourceA, resourceB);

aCostCalculator.calculate(costContainer);
bCostCalculator.calculate(costContainer);
cCostCalculator.calculate(costContainer);
dCostCalculator.calculate(costContainer);
eCostCalculator.calculate(costContainer);
```

Comment: This is the only type-safe solution so far.  And even if the arguments aren't static over the lifetime of the calculators, you could implement a similar mechanism using a wrapper class.

Comment: Well, it looks perfectly valid and clean, while fitting my use case.

Comment: It is already quite beautiful and simple. But let's see if somebody can give another genius answer

Comment: @lesmana Making `CostContainer` a dependency instead of passing it to the `calculate` method would be a better option IMO.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of varying signatures for a common interface sounds a lot like the problem that the [Adapter design pattern (object adapter variant)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13323703/1168342) solves:

[image: Adapter pattern (GoF)]

Applied to your situation, you'd only use adapters to the non-conforming calculators. There are really only two types of adapters, Type1 for signature `(costContainer, resourceA)` and Type2 for signature `(costContainer, resourceA, resourceB)`. Using your example:

[image: Adapter pattern applied to your example]

Advantages of adapter are that it's a known design pattern (published by GoF in 1995), it allows eventual `calculate(...)` methods that have varying signatures. Adapters can be updated dynamically if context changes occur (e.g. resources change).

Disadvantages are obviously the additional classes, the indirection, etc. It's more complicated than the selected answer, but is more flexible particularly if you can't modify the API of the adaptees.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Answer from lesmana don't work if life cycle of resource and cost calculator don't match, e.g. cost calulator is a singleton. Can adapter pattern applied in all situation? I suppose yes (assuming cost calculator is thread safe)?

Comment: @MichaelW.Patterns are always general solutions at the level of the problem they are intended to solve. Applying it to the code is the only way to know for sure. Client code really only sees the Adapters. As long as they're instantiated and managed correctly, it shouldn't matter if the adaptees are singletons. You can add e.g., `setResourceA()`, if you need to change the context of the adapters dynamically. The pattern only provides you with a standard interface. You have to take care for the rest of the (ugly) details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [variadic arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html):

```
public interface CostCalculatorInterface {
    public void calculate(CostContainer container, Object... resources);
}
```

(or replace `Object` with another superclass of `ResourceA` and `ResourceB`).

In the classes implementing the interface, `resources` will be an `Object[]` so you can refer to them as `resources[0]`, `resources[1]` and so on.

Comment: if you pass wrong number of resources an exception may be thrown

Comment: Thanks for asnwering. Type-safe is one of an issue and also for readability. Another programmer may need to spend some effort to find out what "resources[0]" is.

Comment: That's why I don't think my List<Object> (or List<ResourceSuperClass>) solution as a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is something that you actually use with Generics:

```
    Resource resourceA = new ResourceA();
    Resource resourceB = new ResourceB();
    CostContainer costContainer = new CostContainer();
    CostCalculator<Resource> costCalculatorA = new ACostCalculator();
    costCalculatorA.calculate(costContainer,resourceA,resourceB);
    CostCalculator<Resource> costCalculatorB = new BCostCalculator();
    costCalculatorB.calculate(costContainer,resourceA);


interface Resource {
    //Your code
}

class ResourceA implements Resource {
    //Your code
}

class ResourceB implements Resource {
    //Your code
}

class CostContainer {
    //Your code
}

interface CostCalculator<T extends Resource> {
    void calculate(CostContainer costContainer, T... resources);
}

class ACostCalculator implements CostCalculator<Resource>{

    @Override
    public void calculate(CostContainer costContainer, Resource... resources) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}

class BCostCalculator implements CostCalculator<Resource>{

    @Override
    public void calculate(CostContainer costContainer, Resource... resources) {
        System.out.println("Test2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However there is similar flaws same as Glorfindel's answer.