# Is dynamic behavior addition the only advantage of using the Decorator pattern?

Tags: javascript, java, ios, design-patterns

I am studying Decorator design pattern at the moment and this thinking bother me a lot.

Would it be easier just to have one base class with boolean value corresponding to its feature?

For example:
The textview, can have vertical scroll, horizontal scroll, border, etc. if the textview base class has the BOOL for canVerScroll, canHorScroll, hasBorder; why is this not better than Decorator design pattern?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You may have more luck asking this question in the [software engineering stack exchange](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) though I would be aware that [cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) is frowned upon.

Comment: @RicoKahler yeah maybe, sorry I am new to StackOverflow and didn't know they have so many different sites. I might just wait for a while and see if anyone can help in here or I will just move to there instead. Thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be easier just to have one base class with boolean value corresponding to its feature?

This would violate a *SOLID* principle called the *Open-Closed* principle. The *Open-Closed* principle states that components should be open to extension but closed to modification. If you have a single `TextView` class, it will need to be changed every-time you want to introduce a new behavior in your text-view.

> why is this not better than Decorator design pattern?

Imagine that users of your API (who don't have access to your API source code) want to introduce a new behavior for the `TextView` class called *Rotate 360 degrees*. They have two options here, either wait for you to add a new `BOOL` to the `TextView` base class and support this functionality or figure out a way to buid this functionality on top of your `TextView`. One option they could go with is to create a `TextViewAdapter` (read [Adapter pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079605/adapter-any-real-example-of-adapter-pattern)) that will allow them to add the required functionality over and above the functionality that you provided.

Wouldn't it be better if you provided the ability to extend your API out of the box rather than creating an API that is not extensible without your intervention?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! It's awesome to point out the Open-Closed principle that I didn't notice! Are there any good sites that introduce these principles?

Comment: Trying to Summarise the second part you answered. The normal way to solve this problem is by: Decorator design (when suitable) or Adapter pattern on top of it (not quite nice I guess?). And in some language like c# and objective-c, they have class extension. I suppose this does the same work as in extend the class without changing existing code. Am I right in these 3 points? Many thx!

Comment: @TonyLin If you were talking about inheritance when you said class extension, then yes.. That's what extention would mean.