# Converting the interfaces in hierarchical structure in OOD

Tags: oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I have a question about `Facade` design pattern. As i started learning design patterns from the book: **Elements of re-useable object -oriented-software**, there is a good explaination of what it is and how it solves the problem.

This Picture comes from that book:

[image]

**Problem:**
    Suppose i add some extra functionality in the subsystem for which `Domain` is an `Facade/interface`. With this design, i think it's not possible to add extra functionality in the subsystem without changing the `Domain` class?

Second, suppose i use an abstract class `Domain`(to create a hierarchical structure) and delegate all the requests to it's subclasses so that whenever i want to add new functionality , i simply extend my new class/subsystem with `Domain(abstract)`, would that be wrong or still i will have a `Facade` structure?

Same thing happends in `Adapter` pattern. We can have different kind of adapter and instead of hard-coding one class , can we create such an hierarchial structure without violating any OOD rule?

Answer (score 1):

The facade as well as the adapter design patterns are part of the so called  "wrapper" patterns (along with decorator and proxy). They essentially wrap certain functionality and provide a different interface. Their difference is on their intent:

- facade: is used to provide a simple interface to clients, hiding the complexities of the operations it provides behind it
- adapter: allows two incompatible interfaces to work together without changing their internal structure
- decorator: allows new functionalities to be added to an object statically or dynamically without affecting the behavior of objects of the same class
- proxy: a class (proxy) is used to represent and allow access to the
  functionality of another class

If your components "in the back" add new functionality and you want your facade to expose this functionality, you would have to adjust your facade to do so.

If you have the Domain class (facade in your scenario) as an abstract class that others extend, you do not have a facade, you have whatever inheritance you created with your classes. Simply put there is no "wrapping" for achieving the intent of the facade pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> With this design, I think it's not possible to add extra functionality in the subsystem without changing the Domain class?

True. However, the changes you make may (or may not) affect the client (`Process`) class. If you add a *new* method to the Façade, it won't break the "old" clients. Although it's not its explicit intention (which is to hide complexities of a sub-system), Façade can provide a *stable* interface to its clients that can be extended. When I say *interface*, I don't mean a Java or C# interface. It's a programming interface.

A real-world example is the [`JOptionPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) Façade in Java/Swing. Check the Java doc at the link I put and you'll see that some of its methods existed in 1.4, some in 1.6, etc. Basically, since this class is part of a Swing library, it had to remain stable so old clients of it's interface would not break. But it was still *extended* with new functionality by simply adding new methods.

I would say this is how Façades are typically extended, not with sub classing or hierarchy. Hierarchies are difficult to maintain, because they are brittle. If you get the abstraction wrong (the root of the hierarchy), then it affects the entire tree when you need to change it. Hierarchies make sense when the abstraction in the hierarchy is stable (certain).

The Adapter pattern has hierarchy because an Adapter adapts a method to work with several variants of a service that cannot be changed. You can see examples of several stable (abstract) services such as tax calculation, accounting services, credit authorization, etc. at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13323703/1168342.