# Android: change the class extends activities

Tags: android, android-activity, extend

I have a `MainActivity` class that extends `FragmentActivity` and a `SecondActivity` that extends `Fragment`. Now I want to do a class `BaseActivity` and my classes extend it. How I can do? thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, OnClickListener{

    ...

    // THIS LINE USE FRAGMENTACTIVITY ONLY
    mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapaMain)).getMap();

   ...

}

public class SecondActFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, LocationListener { 

      ...
}
```

Comment: Java does not support multiple inheritance, therefore you cannot extend from Activity and Fragment in your base class. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21824485/905349).

Comment: I know it, but I don't know how solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a `BaseActivity`? create a class `BaseFragmentActivity` and extend `FragmentActivity`, override the things you need to override there and then you extend your `MainActivity` as `BaseFragmentActivity` instead

Comment: And the second Activity?

Comment: that's just a Fragment? Edit your post so it's easier to understand your intentions with this

Comment: Yes and Fragments is a view, not an Activity, you use Activitys to host your fragments (FragmentActivity)

Comment: Caun you help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452093/android-class-baseactivity-only-runs-in-mainactivity

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two base classes - BaseActivity (or BaseFragmentActivity) and BaseFragment.