# Implement multiple classification in Java

Tags: java, oop, uml

Is there a way to implement multiple classification in Java? For instance, take this UML diagram -
[image]

How should the `GrainCrop` class be implemented?

Comment: Look at this example: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824402/java-multiple-inheritance

Comment: Yes indeed the question has been asked before. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not support multiple inheritance on classes, only interfaces can inherit from multiple interfaces. So what I would do is that the Class `GrainCrop` in question implements the interface from the two other classes. Then `GrainCrop` aggregates the two other classes and delegates to the "inner" objects. The calls in `GrainCrop` can then also be decorated if you need to do additional stuff. E.g.

```
public void methodFromClassCrop() {
    System.out.println("Stuff before call");
    oneOfTheObjects.methodFromClassCrop();
    System.out.println("Stuff after call");
}
```

Of course you can only introduce an interface for one of the classes and inherit from the other. It depends on the question if your new class extends one of the other classes in a sense of: introduce new behavior, algorithm, data which uses the other data, or if you just "act" (aggregation in this case) on them.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces.  One or both of `Crop` and `FoodItem` would be an interface to be implemented by `GrainCrop`.  So either:

1. `GrainCrop` *is* a `Crop` (and inherits its behaviors) and *exhibits the behavior* of `FoodItem`.  In this case `Crop` is a base class (potentially abstract) and `FoodItem` is an interface.
2. `GrainCrop` *is* a `FoodItem` (and inherits its behaviors) and *exhibits the behavior* of `Crop`.  In this case `FoodItem` is a base class (potentially abstract) and `Crop` is an interface.
3. `GrainCrop` exhibits the behaviors of both `FoodItem` and `Crop`.  In this case both `FoodItem` and `Crop` are interfaces.

In a single-inheritance environment you take specific care to identify what something "is" vs. what behaviors it exhibits.  (This is one of the reasons why interfaces are often described by their behaviors, such as `Eatable`, rather than their structure, such as `FoodItem`.  It makes the modeling more clear.)

As an often handy over-simplification, think of a base class as what something "is" and an interface as what something "does."  An object can only *be* one thing, but it can *do* many things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given the fact that FeedItem doesn't appear to have any implementation, I would make it an interface, make Crop a class (possibly abstract), and have GrainCrop extend both of them. You can only extend one class, but you can extend as many interfaces as you want.