# How to inherites JPanel and another class?

Tags: java, jpanel

I've got a little problem. I am trying to do a simple Java2D Game with friends. My work is to do a drawing a game on the JPanel.

There is:

abstract class GameBase

with the simple logic of game, which I have to extends.

Then I need another
class extends JPanel implements ActionListener

to draw on it and get actions from the player.

How to contains all of it in one class? I hope you will understand what I want to do :)

Thank's

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Multiple Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824402/java-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to bind or connect your classes with references together. 
For Example:

```
class firstExampleClass extends firstExtendedClass{

    LogicalExampleClass panelSample;

    public firstExampleClass(){
       //BIND or connect via Relationship

    }
}

class logicalExampleClass extends secondExtendedClass{

}
```