# How to inherit from two classes

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a `People` class, and `Student` and `Employee` classes which inherit from it. But if I have a person who is both a `Student` and an `Employee`...

... How would you go about implementing this?

Comment: I wouldn't make them classes. So what's the actual problem?

Comment: @Ordous why not make classes?

Comment: @SihanWang What **exactly** is the problem? What functionality do `Student` and `Employee` need to have?

Comment: It feels like a bad design, can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: @Mureinik it is a interview question, i think you can make any assumption here.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno it is a interview question, i think you can make any assumption here

Comment: Since Java does not support multiple inheritances you basically have three options - a) rethink the design having business concepts in class layout is not always a good fit. b) use interfaces, you can implement multiple. c) use composition (having a personInfo and a studentInfo field)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Multiple Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824402/java-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 18):

That's a classic example of an improperly analyzed problem domain. Yes, in some situations, it may be proper to think of "Student" as a type of "Person" and an "Employee" as a type of "Person", but - depending on your problem domain - it may also not be appropriate.

If your domain requires that something be both a "Student" and an "Employee", you should consider if the relation between "Student" and "Person" *in your problem domain* is really an "is-a" relationship.

It could be that in this particular case, being a student is merely *an attribute* of a particular person. So, John Doe is a person, who may also have a "current occupation" of "Student". In this case, he may have a list of several "current occupations". And the relationship in such a world becomes "has-a" rather than "is-a". So "Student" and "Employee" become subclasses of "Occupation".

Comment: I get the point, but I did not get how to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: It's a bit hard to give you a concrete example, without knowing what you were asked to implement in your interview. Perhaps you should add the full interview question text to your original question.

Answer (score 17):

As per the comment:

> it is a interview question, i think you can make any assumption here

If this is the case, the only correct answer is to describe your assumptions, and how you address them.

If you strictly adhere to the requirements, you could make `Student` and `Employee` interfaces and have different classes implement them:

```
public interface Student {
    void learn();
}

public interface Employee {
    void work();
}

public class Person {
    // properties, getters and setters for name, age, sex, etc.
}

public class StudentPerson extends Person implements Student {
    @Override
    public void learn() {}
}

public class EmployeePerson extends Person implements Employee {
    @Override
    public void work() {}
}
public class StudentEmployeePerson extends Person implements Student, Employee {
    @Override
    public void work();

    @Override
    public void learn() {}
}
```

Taking this an extra mile would be to extract the logic of `work()` and `learn()` to helper classes, and have `StudentPerson`, `EmployeePerson` and `StudentEmployeePerson` call them respectively.

But this, IMHO, missed the point of the exercise.

A student who also has a job is still a student. He cannot be a separate class from a student who doesn't.

I'd create a `Role` interface, have `Student` and `Employee` implement it, and allow a `Person` to have multiple `Role`s, so he can be **both** a student and an employee:

```
public interface Role {
    void perform();
}

public class Student implements Role {
    @Override
    void perform() { /* go study */ }
}

public class Employee implements Role {
    @Override
    void perform() { /* go work */ }
}

public class Person {
    // properties, getters and setters for name, age, sex, etc.

    private Set<Role> roles = /* initialized somehow */

    public void doStuff() {
        for (Role role : roles) {
            role.perform();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
To answer the question in the comment, a person who is both a student and an employee would be constructed by adding `Role`s. For simplicity's sake the snippet below assumes that these classes have constructors from the relevant properties, and that `Person` has methods to add and remove the `Role`s to the internal set:

```
Person person = new Person("John Doe", 21, Sex.Male);
person.addRole(new Student("Stack Overflow University"));
person.addRole(new Employee("Secret Government Spy"));
```

Comment: That is the first time I see the second solution. In this case, how could instantiate for one person who are student and employee?  Thank you

Comment: @SihanWang I've edited my answer with an example of how this can be done.

Comment: if we want to have a student, would we use function addRole of Person, or just use Student class?

Comment: @SihanWang In the second implementation - you'd have a `Person`, with a single `Student` role. If this is a common usecase, it might be worth adding a constructor with a `Set<Role>` or even `Role` parameter as syntactic sugar: `new Person ("John Doe", 21, Sex.Male, Collections.singleton(new Student("NYU")))` or even `new Person ("John Doe", 21, Sex.Male, new Student("NYU"))`

Comment: This is very beautiful design.

Comment: I am new to java, is there disadvantage for the second solution comparing with the first one?

Comment: @SihanWang the main problem, IMHO, is that you don't have a good way to restrict the types of people you can pass to method. E.g., it'll be quite clumsy to create a `Classroom` class which holds a list of students, whereas in the first solution, you could just have `Classroom(List<Student>)`. In the end, in all boils down to what the requirements are.

Answer (score 4):

Since Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance you should define interfaces for `Student` and `Employee` instead of inheriting from them as base classes.

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is, you can change the `public class Employee` to `public interface Employee` and then you can do `public class Student extends People implements Employee`

You will have to work like this because in java, one class can inherit only from one class at the most.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In Java it is only possible to extend one superclass. However, Java offers interfaces and one class can extend more than one interface.

You could organize your class structure like this:

```
interface People
interface Student extends People
interface Employee extends People
```

Then your employing students could be:

```
class EmployingStudent implements Student, Employee
```

---

In case `People` is a class that cannot be changed you can do:

```
interface Student
interface Employee
class EmployingStudent implements Student, Employee
```

So the only difference would be that Student and Employee wouldn't extend People then.

Comment: what if we have people class, that can not change