# Return sub class type from super type method

Tags: java, generics

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T extends BaseClass<T>> {

    T method1(){
        return getThis();
    }

    public  abstract T getThis();
}

public class SubClass extends BaseClass<SubClass> {
    public SubClass getThis(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

If it's just one level of inheritance i can do something like the above and get a reference of SubClass when I call method1().

What if I have inheritance at two levels like

```
public abstract class SubClass1<T extends SubClass1<T>> extends BaseClass<SubClass1<T>> {
    @Override
    public SubClass1<T> getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}

public class SubSubClass1 extends SubClass1<SubSubClass1> {



}
```

what should I change to the method1 and BaseClass so that when method1 is called I can get back SubSubClass1 type. I wan't to do this without any suppress warnings

Comment: Though I have no complete idea, I have a question. In java how can a class can extend two classes at a time? I mean can we use extends keyword on a class two times?

Comment: @TheGuest: It cannot **directly** extend 2 classes. But it can implement as many interfaces as you like. You can restrict a type parameter with multiple bounds however, if you use `&`.

Comment: @TheGuest Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824402/java-multiple-inheritance).  It's a pretty comprehensive explanation.

Comment: @fabian I know that, but where is the OP implementing an interface?

Comment: @TheGuest, the example does not involve a class extending two classes.  One of the two 'extends' keywords applies to type parameter `T`, not to class `SubClass1`.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but maybe simple  ["Covariant method return type"](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) can do it, no genrics needed.

Comment: The bound on `T` is useless in your case. `public abstract class BaseClass<T>` would compile just as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to understand that each type-parameterized class's type parameters are its own.  In particular, they (the parameters themselves) are not shared with super- or subclasses.  It is common for type-parameterized subclasses to intentionally share type parameter *values* with their superclasses, but that's a different thing.

Classes get to specify their superclasses, but they do not get to alter their superclass' own inheritance.  Thus, if `SubClass1` extends `BaseClass<SubClass1<T>>` then `BaseClass`'s type parameter for class `SubClass1<T>` *and every subclass thereof* is `SubClass1<T>`, because that class alone is the one that `SubClass1<T>` extends.

Any concrete subclass of your `BaseClass<T>` must implement its abstract method `getThis()`, and that requires such a class (e.g. `SubClass1`) to specify `BaseClass`'s type parameter `T` as an instantiable type (else it cannot provide a return value).  From that point on down the hierarchy, subclasses can employ covariant return types to narrow the type returned by `getThis()`, but they cannot change the `BaseClass` type parameter specified by `SubClass1`, except to the extent that it depends on `SubClass1`'s own type parameter(s).  For example, this compiles cleanly:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T extends BaseClass<T>> {
    // ...
    public  abstract T getThis();
}

public abstract class SubClass1<T extends SubClass1<T>> extends BaseClass<SubClass1<T>> {
    @Override
    public SubClass1<T> getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}

public class SubSubClass1 extends SubClass1<SubSubClass1> {
    @Override
    public SubSubClass1 getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

But that's an exercise of covariant return types, not type parameterization, so this also works:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    // ...
    public abstract BaseClass getThis();
}

public abstract class SubClass1 extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    public SubClass1 getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}

public class SubSubClass1 extends SubClass1 {
    @Override
    public SubSubClass1 getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Props to @HannoBinder who first suggested covariant return types in the comments.

Note that if the main idea here was use a type parameter to mark which descendant of `BaseClass` you actually have -- or at least an upper bound on that -- then that's wrongheaded.  In that approach, the type `BaseClass<SomeSubClass>` is no more meaningful or expressive than the type `SomeSubClass` itself.  The parameterized version is distinguished only by being harder to work with.

Comment: new SubSubClass1().method1() would still return SubClass1 here not SubSubClass1

Comment: This was not really the intent of the OP. Consider this snippet : `BaseClass bc = new SubSubClass1(); bc.getThis();`. As I understand the question, the OP would like `bc.getThis()` of the type `SubSubClass1` at compile time, which is not the case here : it is `BaseClass`

Comment: It's hard to tell just what the intent of the OP was, but I think my answer is anyway about the best he can do.  I have updated it with some comments about why that's so.

Comment: If what he wants to achieve is impossible then that's what your answer should be telling, instead of providing an answer to a slightly different question. Basically the OP wants to be able to get the *runtime* type of a class while using polymorphism

Comment: Very well.  I have updated the answer to explain why the OP cannot have what he seems to be asking.  I have retained the part that gives an alternative that may be viable for him, and the part that explains why what he thought he wanted is not a useful objective (which raises the value of the offered alternative).

Answer (score 1):

`SubSubClass1` must be the one implementing `getThis()`, like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> {
    T method1(){
        return getThis();
    }
    public abstract T getThis();
}

public abstract class SubClass1<T> extends BaseClass<T> {
}

public class SubSubClass1 extends SubClass1<SubSubClass1> {
    @Override
    public SubSubClass1 getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}
```