# Extend HashMap and LinkedHashMap at the Same Time?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, hashmap

I want to extend `HashMap` to add the method `putIfGreaterThan` which basically retrieves the value for a given key and if the new value is greater than the old value we update the old value with the new value. Like this:

```
  public void putIfGreaterThan(String key, Double value )
  {

  if (containsKey(key ) != true) {
  put( key , value );
  } else {
  if (get(key ) < value) {
  System. out .println("Adding new value: " + value + " to map" );
  put( key , value );
  } else {
  System. out .println("Did not add value: " + value + " to map" );
  }
  }


  }
```

The program above works fine - however I would like to add this method to both `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap`. In other words, if someone instantiates:

```
HashMap hashmap = new HashMap();
```

They should be able to access the method:

```
hashmap.putIfGreaterThan();
```

And if someone instantiates:

```
LinkedHashMap linkedhashmap = new LinkedHashMap();
```

They should be able to access the method:

```
linkedhashmap .putIfGreaterThan();
```

If I create a new class as follows:

`MyHashMap extends HashMap<String, Double>` and add the previously mentioned method - I am only extending `HashMap` not `LinkedHashMap`. This would not allow me to access the method if I instantiate a `LinkedHashMap`.

I was thinking of modifying the source code in the original HashMap class (by adding the method `putIfGreaterThan`) however I am unable to modify the source code unless I de-compile the entire class (and when I try doing this I get a bunch of other errors so I figured it would be easier just to extend the `HashMap` class but doing this means I cannot use the method `putIfGreaterThan` on both `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap`).

Further, if I had added the method to the original class one would be able to call this method on any `HashMap` (even if the map contains two Strings) but the method is only applicable on a HashMap that contains String and Double or String and Int. Hence, I think it makes more sense to extend the original class and customize the current class with methods related to a `HashMap` of String and Double.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest using composition. Make your class have a hashmap,  then wrap the put method of the map with your logic.

Comment: Modifying the behavior of the HashMap class itself, not just your own custom class, cannot be done, and for good reason:  it would introduce a security nightmare for Java applications everywhere.

Comment: Why the redundant `if (containsKey(key ) != true)` instead of the straightforward `if (! containsKey(key))`?

Comment: Don't modify the core API. You're aware that Java forbids multiple inheritance of implementation (classes), and only permits multiple inheritance of interfaces, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your custom map implement the `Map` interface instead and wrap a concrete map with it that is provided by the user of the class via the constructor:

```
public class MyMap implements Map<String, Double>{
    private final Map<String, Double> map;  

    public MyMap(Map<String, Double> map){
        this.map = map;
    }

    public void putIfGreaterThan(String key, Double value ){...}

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    //inherited methods
}
```

This class can be used like this:

```
MyMap map = new MyMap(new LinkedHashMap<>());
```

or:

```
MyMap map = new MyMap(new HashMap<>());
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `putIfGreaterThan(K key, V value)` here?

Comment: If I implement the Map interface I am forced to add 12 unimplemented methods such as size(), containsKey() and isEmpty(). I now need to add the body to each method. Seems like a lot of extra work just to define 1 new method..

Comment: @KevinLittle You only need to call the corresponding method of the wrapped map in the bodies of the inherited methods like I did for `size()` in my answer: `public boolean isEmpty(){return map.isEmpty()}` and so on

Comment: OK makes sense. I think I'm going to accept this answer however I was wondering why this method is superior than the method suggested by @chatton (to use composition) - I do not need to add unimplemented methods with that strategy.. Also why do you suggest I use K, V  over <String, Double> (if I'm only defining methods that apply to String, Double or String, Int) Thanks!

Comment: @KevinLittle If you want a String, Double map `<String, Double>` makes sense - I changed it. Wrapping a given map is composition - the custom map HAS an other map. The benefit you get of additionally implementing the Map interface is that the custom map not only HAS a map, but also IS a map itself. This way you can use the custom map like any other map.

Answer (score 0):

Java don't support multi inheritance, but you can be done using Interfaces.

[Java Multiple Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824402/java-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add your method to the existing HashMap or LinkedHashMap class.
Only way is to create a custom class `MyHashMap<K,V>` which implements the `Map` interface and put your logic there and compose that class with `HashMap` and(or) `LinkedHashMap` and let your clients operate on `MyHashMap`.