# Can I access methods of different class having diff properties using single object?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

*NOTE : This question was asked to me in an Interview*

We have 3 classes having different properties.

```
class A{}

class B extends A{}

class C extends A{}
```

Can I call any method present among these 3 classes with a **Single Obj ?**

I got confused because **class B** don't have properties of **class C** and viceversa.

**Is there any way to make this possible ?**

Comment: so you did answer no you can't, right?

Comment: The question isn't clear. Obviously not with the exact declarations given.

Comment: I said sorry I don't know.

Comment: :) that is a terrible start in an interview  - you just stated the reason in your last statement

Comment: @Rajat Sangrame, I think you are asked about "Diamond Problem" in an interview and you can search more about it on internet.

Comment: He also told me that this concept is used in Android.

Comment: @RajatSangrame *What* "concept"? From `C` you cannot call `B` instance methods with the declarations as shown--there is no relationship between `B` and `C` other than they share the same parent class.

Comment: @DaveNewton Exactly.. Thats what I though. But he showed me some example calling a AdaperClass from MainActivity and was talking some shit about Modals. I didn't get it.

Comment: @RajatSangrame And you were correct--with the declarations shown it isn't possible. If you create a *new* class that composites a `B` and `C` *then* you can. Not until then. (There are a few other mechanisms as well, even without getting into byte-code manipulation, which is another option.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question that you were asked was about Diamond Problem, you can check more about it here. --> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-inheritance-in-c/

Coming to your Question, as Java does not support multiple inheritance, you can't call any method present among these 3 classes with a Single Object. For solving this "Diamond Problem", Java has something called Interfaces. So, Android supports java and "Interfaces" is the concept that the interviewer was talking about to solve "Diamond Problem" in Android and Java.

Comment: Can you explain this i code ? I mean using a single object.

Comment: There are many examples online available for this "Diamond Problem".you can surely look at this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824402/java-multiple-inheritance

Comment: Okay :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I call any method present among these 3 classes with a Single Obj
>   ?

You could not call any method. Only method declared in A class with any object with A type of reference

Comment: I don't think you got the point, you can call a method from `A` with a reference of type `B` as long as that method is inherited.

Comment: Is there any way to do this possible ? May be I am missing any declaration. He also told me this concept is used in Anroid