# How to extends two utilities classes?

Tags: java, user-interface, timer

I extended two classes (`TimerTask` and `Jframe`) to my class but it shows me an error, is there any way to correct the error? I need them to set a timer in my GUI classes.

Comment: Post the error that you get along with your code in the question.

Comment: In Java, a class cannot extend two classes, but it can extend one and implement many interfaces.

Comment: Read this Q&A - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824402/java-multiple-inheritance

Comment: You should be able to set a timer in your `JFrame` subclass without making it a subclass of `TimerTask`.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support multiple inheritance. You cannot extend two class in Java. However, you can implement multiple interfaces but not extend multiple class. Try to rethink your design to handle it in a different way.