# Can we use multiple extends of class in java selenium?

Tags: java, class, extends

Please explain how to extend two classes from different packages.

public class Animal extends Herbivores extends Omnivores {
}

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/21824402/6400036

Answer (score 4):

Multiple Inheritance or **Diamond Inheritance** is a feature of object oriented concept, where a class can inherit properties of more than one parent class.

**Java does not support that.**

There are multiple resources over the net which tells you the problem that arises if you are allowed to do that.

Coming to your problem, it seems to me like **a fault in Design.**

**Animal should be a parent type rather than a child type. Both Herbivores and Omnivores are animals. Whereas an animal doen't necessary have to be either. It can be a carnivore also.**